# Stopping a service once it has finished it's work

Tags: android

I have an Android Service that is started by my application and does some things in a threadPool using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

Once it has finished doing it's work I would like the service to `stopSelf()`, how can I get the service to determine when it is no longer needed (ie, there are no more Threads executing) so that it can shut itself down automatically?

Comment: FYI, if you do not need multiple threads, consider using an `IntentService`, which handles a background thread and work queue for you, and automatically shuts down when the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way: the last `Runnable` should shut the `Service` upon completion.

Comment: But I don't know what the last runnable will be.

Comment: @jax
To know which `Runnable` will be the last one, you can a)use a single-threaded `Executor` or b)implement a simple simple counter that will be incremented each time you submit a `Runnable` and then decremented by `Runnable` upon completion.